# Codeigniter search with multiple fields

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I've tried to make a `search field` with two parameters. One for `name` and the other one for `location`. But my code returns only the results for the first parameter. Maybe someone could figure out what's wrong.
Below it's my code.

Mode:

```
public function search_job($keyword, $location){
    $query = $this->db->like('name', $keyword)
                ->like('location', $location)
                ->or_like('description', $keyword)
                ->get('jobs');

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function search_job(){
    $location = $this->input->post('location');
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');

    if ($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $this->Job_model->search_job($keyword, $location);
    }
}
```

Comment: after get() do echo $this->db->last_query(); and show what it prints

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `jobs`
WHERE `name` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'
AND  `location` LIKE '%africa%' ESCAPE '!'
OR  `description` LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve ? can you write normal MySQL for it.

Comment: if i search for boston in location i want to be returned only the jobs from boston, no matter the job name. if i search for php in name i wanna return the jobs with php in name/description no matter the location.

Comment: and logic behind keyword ?

Comment: keyword its the search field for name, description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your query is getting messed up when no `$keyword` is passed, try below query.

**Code :**

```
public function search_job($keyword, $location){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('jobs');
    if(!empty($keyword)) {
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->like('name', $keyword);
        $this->db->or_like('description', $keyword);
        $this->db->group_end();
    }
    $this->db->like('location', $location);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: You're code returns all jobs no matter the name, location when i write something on the location input

Comment: oh snap...during my work I've found a bug, if you search a job name like Warehouse and location Africa it will return every Warehouse job even if the location it's not Africa

Comment: try updated code. check if it works in your scenario

Comment: thanks again man! sorry for that, I didn't check from the first time

Comment: no issues, you can't check every scenario in one go :)